# How to create new View Controllers in XCode 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I have figured out that in XCode 4.3, to create a new ViewController, I have to do New > Objective-C Class, then subclass UIViewController. But, how come the xib checkbox is greyed out? How do I create a new view controller with an xib?

[image]

Comment: I've been working with objective-c for 20 years, including every version of Xcode, and I just made this mistake. This probably saved me an hour of head banging. Just goes to show there are no stupid questions.

Comment: I have been writing Objective-C for 5 years since Xcode 3, also just made this mistake. Coding at midnight is never a good idea :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add an OS X Objective-C class to an iOS project

[image]

which produces this..

[image]

Instead add the new file like this..

[image]

which produces this..

[image]

Comment: Yet another example of confusing UX from Apple

Comment: Its 2016 and I am using XCode7 instead of 4.3. The answer is still valid

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the xib box is grayed out (doesn't happen for me), but you can always just go to new file and create a nib from there and set its class to your `UIViewController` subclass in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, just select the UIViewController again in the **Subclass of** combo and it will be  enabled again.

Happened to me when i canceled the creation once and opened the dialog again.