# How to handle large amounts of text within iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm creating a universal ios app. In the app there's a story that I'd like to manually put into the app, not pulled from a server. It's not a an *extremely* large amount of text, but it's enough that I want it split up into different pages.

My question is: What's the best way of putting a lot of text into an app with pages that the user can just scroll through?

WARNING: I'm pretty new to programming in general, this is my first iOS app. You don't have to provide me any code, if you could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic!

-- The app is being made in storyboard if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this.

1. You can do this by showing the text on multiple views
2. Using a scroll view.
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3cgi36sY-k
3. Unsing a page view Controller.

links in the comments below

Comment: multiple views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708936/how-to-create-new-view-controllers-in-xcode-4-3

Comment: Page controller:http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Comment: pageviewcontroller in apple lib.:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. You don't need to have a `UITextView` inside a `UIScrollView`, unless you want to add multiples views into it.

You can create a `UITextView` that takes the whole screen in a `UIViewController` like this:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
myTextView.text = @"some large text";
myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
myTextView.editable = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
```

The property contentSize will be set automatically depending on the size of the text. You can also use `[myTextView sizeToFit]` method to resize the `UITextView` to fit its text.