# How do I add a new view to a single view application in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I started my app as a single view application. I have the view with various buttons and labels connected to code. I want to add a button that links to another view.

I found a tutorial that guided me to click on the project and add a UIView subclass. However there is no option for that ( I think because I started it as a single view application).

I'm pretty new to all this so if anyone can outline a simple way for me to do this that would be great! I am using Xcode version 4.3.2.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. I have the .xib that shows the view and then a .h and .m where I put the code. I'm not sure I would even know if I was, but there is nothing I am using that I can see that says storyboard.

Comment: Storyboarding is an option that makes making new views, and connecting them much easier.  Might want to start with a blank project and test it out. When you name a new project, there is a "Use Storyboards" checkbox that you can check.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to convert what I have or are you suggesting I  transfer all my code over and reconnect everything in a new project started with the Story Boards option? I would like to avoid having to redo work unless I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new `Objective C class`. Please refer to this:

[How to create new View Controllers in XCode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708936/how-to-create-new-view-controllers-in-xcode-4-3)

Comment: @Herbie if you continue without storyboards, make sure to check the 'with XIB for user interface' checkbox.

Comment: Thank You! That is looking good. I still need to figure out how to set up a button in my first view to link to the next view and back. But I can probably work that out. This was the piece I was struggling with, thank for the help (including the bit about making sure to check ('with XIB') !!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you started the app as single view using xib file the to add a class just go to name of the project on the left pane and right click on it. Then choose add new file. The pop up will appear to allow you to choose what type of class you want to add. Depending to what the new view is you can choose uiview controller or uitableview controller and so on. Just make sure you check mark with xib for interface user. That should do it. Hope it helps.
Adrian

Comment: Thank you. However those options do not appear when I select the add a new file option. I watched someone do this on a video and they had option appear like UIView Controller etc. However when I go there those options are missing. All the other options are there. I was thinking this is because I started the project as a Single View application. So maybe I can not add a view?